# Linux Cannot change tx-checksumming

Tags: vmware-esx, linux-networking, linux-kernel

On a Linux 3.2 kernel:
Linux 3.2.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.2.46-1+deb7u1 i686 GNU/Linux
on VmWare, i get checksum errors on ipv6 tcp packets.

So I can ping6, but not connect by ipv6 to ssh, smtp, html etc.

I believe, according to http://www.tunnelbroker.net/forums/index.php?topic=2826.0 I have to disable checksum offloading.

I'm supposed to do use this, but it doesn't work.

```
host:~#  ethtool --offload  eth0  rx off  tx off
Cannot change rx-checksumming
Cannot change tx-checksumming
Could not change any device features
host:~# ethtool -K eth0 gso off
Could not change any device features
```

Other options?

Hosts with 2.6 kernel does not have this problem; server was ok until upgraded to a 3.2 kernel.

Comment: Does ipv6 work correctly from the host?

Comment: Ping, traceroute nmap works.
I have the symptoms of https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=438458 where tcp-6 packets woth payload have checksum errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned off checksum offloading at the virtual switches.

https://communities.vmware.com/thread/167737

In short, ssh'ing to each physixal esx-server, in /etc/vmware/esx.conf setting

```
/net/vswitch/child[xxxx]/capabilities/ChecksumOffload = "false"
```